# Replace year in the existing table table on Date.Month.Year format

Tags: sql, db2-400, sql-query-store

How can I replace the only year from my table and return the result  (within a Select) ?

I have an existing table with Date column Date.Month.Year format some of the rows have default values as 01.01.0001 now I want to replace the year in rows with 01.01.0001 as 01.01.1000 for all rows with 01.01.0001 (within a Select)

Comment: Please tag only one RDBMS. Are you using Db2 or are you using mysql. Different answers might apply to different RDBMS.  If Db2, You have to know exactly the Db2-datatype for this column, is it CHAR(...) or VARCHAR(...) or DATE or something else.  With correct datatype knowledge, you can use `SELECT ... FROM FINAL TABLE ( UPDATE .... SET ... WHERE... ) `

Comment: Do you want to update the default column values in the table and show updated values or just show new values with SELECT? If latter, then you may use just a simple CASE expression with SELECT, which has the same form in many RDBMS.

Comment: Hi @mao,
My column name is  is M1 date which is having below date like 0001.01.01 in a table name Date_ks. now I want to replace only the Year 0001 to other year like 0100 IN THE FORMAT LIKE 0100.01.01 and I want to replace the all the rows which are with 0001.01.01 to 0100.01.01 In that particular column using within select.
I am using DB2 and data type is DATE

Comment: Try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=58323af0fe4d6c9ba908f3b3e3613edb) as is.

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein,
Tried but no luck below is the error
03-08-2022 13:11:58 Error ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token : was not valid. Valid tokens: + - THEN.
ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]PWS0005 - Error occurred in the database host server code.

Below is the code used:
SELECT 
CASE M1DATE 
  WHEN '0001-01-01'::DATE THEN '0100-01-01'::DATE
  ELSE M1DATE
END AS M1DATE_NEW
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  CURRENT DATE
, '0001-01-01'::DATE
) KWDB108.KWLBASE (M1DATE)

Comment: Db2 for IBM i doesn't have such a data type casting syntax as Db2 for LUW. Look at the [updated example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=63e15301fc9651a065177a406f1fe174).

Comment: Its working @MarkBarinstein but I need to replace in  the existing column as we are creating new column I hope so, Also its not replacing all the rows with records 0001-01-01 to 0100-01-01

Comment: Please, provide a link with fully reproducible example of your problem as I did it above.